# How to change polylang flag?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I need different flag for languages.

> It is possible to use your own images as flags. You have to use PNG or JPG files and name them with the WordPress locale. For example, en_GB.png. Then upload this file in the /wp-content/polylang/ directory (create the directory if it does not exist). Don’t use the /polylang/flags/ directory as your file would be removed when automatically updating the plugin.
>
> Once the custom flag is uploaded, go in Languages > Settings > URL modifications module then click on save changes. Note that your custom flags are not used on admin side.

I did all of this but the language switcher have the same flags... I don't see how the plugin would recognize that if I place an en_GB.png file in its directory (Not the flags folder). Feels like they miss something important, how to assign the images to certain language...

Comment: As the instructions say, you have to use the actual WP locale, in example on my installation I have en_US end others, but not en_GB, thus a flag named en_GB wouldn't be found, try to rename it in en_US.png to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I modify flags, with CSS using title attribute, example:

```
img[title="English"] {
    width: 50px !important;
    height: 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, just bear in mind to inspect the img before adding the CSS code. For my situation it was alt not title.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go ssh/ftp (or any other way) to add a folder under `/wp-content`.
Your structure will look like:

```
> uploads
> themes
> polylang (this is your new folder)
> plugins
> languages
> index.php
```

Then create a PNG (preferably) or JPEG image for your flag (16x16px dimensions are good enough) and name it accordingly. For example for English you have to name the file as `en_US.png` (you can find the codes inside your plugin for each language).
Upload your image under `/wp-content/polylang` directory and go to your WordPress administration panel under `Languages > Settings > URL modifications (just open this and hit save)`.
Refresh your browser and get your results!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You can use PNG, JPG or even SVG files and name them with the WordPress locale. For example, en_US.png.

Upload these files in the /wp-content/polylang/ directory.

Note: You have to create the directory yourself. Don’t use the /polylang/flags/ directory as your files would be removed when automatically updating the plugin. Alternatively, it’s possible to store the files in the /polylang/ subdirectory of the theme or the child theme.

Once the custom flags are uploaded, go to Languages > Settings. Click on the “URL modifications” settings and then on Save Changes.

Comment: Did you just copy the official polylang answer that the original author also quoted? sorry but I can't see how this answers the question - if you got it to work, please explain the steps